# How can I make a triangle drawable on the top left of my view?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have created this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="10"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="-0%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"   >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/color_primary"  />
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

On the preview it looks like this:

[image]

And I have put it into this `View`:

```
        <View
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

And this `View` looks like this on the preview (and on the phone):

[image]

Why doesn't the `View` just show the triangle on the corner like on the triangle preview? Also, I should mention that I want it to fill half of the `View` square, basically go from the the top right corner to the bottom left corner.

Thanks.

Edit: I was given a suggestion to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="-135"
            android:pivotX="90%"
            android:pivotY="-45%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"   >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/color_primary"  />
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And that does produce a corner triangle but it doesn't fill half of the `View` square. This is what it does:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would solve this by using a `<vector>` drawable instead of a `<layer-list>`.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/color_primary"
        android:pathData="M0 24v-24h24z"/>

</vector>
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make a rounded corner triangle with vector? Can you help with that?

Comment: if you want to use it on the right side of the view, you can rotate it to 90 degrees

Comment: @neilQ5 you can also change the pathData to `M0 0h24v24z` to draw the triangle on the upper right (i.e. start at `0,0`, horizontal line by `24`, vertical line by `24`, close the shape).

Comment: in my opinion very stupid syntax... took me 5 mins to find the other way around. `android:pathData="M0,24 h24 v-24 z"`

Comment: It's definitely not the most readable, but if you think of it as a mechanical pen I find that helps. The original can be read as `move pen to 0,24 and put it on the paper`, then `move pen up 24 units`, then `move pen right 24 units`, and finally `move pen to the start position and lift it off the paper` (with an implied `fill in the shape`). For you, you want to `move to 0,24`, `right 24 units`, `up 24 units`, and `back to start`.

Comment: How to add Rounded corner to left edge of the triangle ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML to the following and it will work as you want it to.

triangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="-135"
            android:pivotX="90%"
            android:pivotY="-45%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"   >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/color_primary"  />
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp8Ti.jpg)
[Device screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16sOt.jpg):

Comment: While that puts it in the corner, it doesn't fill half of the `View` square which is what I wanted. I'm adding a picture to my post.